# Match certain column values with other multiple

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame, df, where I would like to take certain values from multiple columns and append them to other columns given certain criteria.

**Data**

```
id  value type_a         pos date   stat    type_b       id   date2
aaa 10    aaa_q2.25_1    30  q1.22  aaa               
aaa 20    aaa_q3.25_2    30  q1.22  aaa               
aaa 500   aaa_q1.22_3    30  q1.22  aaa     aaa_q1.22_3  aaa
bbb 20    bbb_q1.22_1    20  q1.22  bbb     bbb_q1.22_1  bbb
bbb 10    bbb_q3.25_4    20  q2.22  bbb               
aaa 5     aaa_q2.22_3    30  q2.22  aaa     aaa_q2.22_3  aaa
ccc 15    ccc_q3.22_1    50  q3.22  ccc     ccc_q3.22_1  ccc  
                                    ccc     ccc_q4.26_2  ccc q1.22            
                                    aaa     ccc_q2.22_2  aaa q1.22
                                    ccc     ccc_q2.22_3  ccc q1.22
```

**Desired**

Logic, for the empty column spaces of 'id', 'typea' and 'date', take the values from the columns, 'stat', 'typeb' and 'date2' and apply them to 'id',   'typea', and 'date'

```
id  value type_a         pos date   stat    type_b       id    date2
aaa 10    aaa_q2.25_1    30  q1.22  aaa               
aaa 20    aaa_q3.25_2    30  q1.22  aaa               
aaa 500   aaa_q1.22_3    30  q1.22  aaa     aaa_q1.22_3  aaa
bbb 20    bbb_q1.22_1    20  q1.22  bbb     bbb_q1.22_1  bbb
bbb 10    bbb_q3.25_4    20  q2.22  bbb              
aaa 5     aaa_q2.22_3    30  q2.22  aaa     aaa_q2.22_3  aaa
ccc 15    ccc_q3.22_1    50  q3.22  ccc     ccc_q3.22_1  ccc
ccc       ccc_q4.26_2    50  q1.22  ccc     ccc_q4.26_2  ccc  q1.22           
aaa       aaa_q2.22_2    30  q1.22  aaa     aaa_q2.22_2  aaa  q1.22
ccc       ccc_q2.22_3    50  q1.22  ccc     ccc_q2.22_3  ccc  q1.22
```

**Doing**

A SO member has pointed me in the right direction and the code works well, however, I am wanting to manipulate more than one column on this particular problem.

```
df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(df['stat'].str[:3])
df['typea'] = df['typea'].fillna(df['typeb'].str[:11])
df['date'] = df['date'].fillna(df['date2'].str[:5])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `fillna()`:

```
df.iloc[:,0]=df.iloc[:,0].fillna(df['stat'])
#you have to use iloc since you have 2 columns of name 'id'
df['type_a']=df['type_a'].fillna(df['type_b'])
df['date']=df['date'].fillna(df['date2'])
```

Comment: Thank you- it is saying SyntaxError: invalid syntax   and it points to" df['date']=df['date'].fillna()df['date2']

Comment: @Lynn corrected syntax...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Oh I fix it - ok